# Paired sample t-test to compare the accuracy of missing data imputation methods

Tags: correlation, t-test, mean, missing-data

I have an assignment to compare an original data set (N = 100, 14 variables, 5 of which are nominal) with complete values to another version of the same data set with missing values imputed from 3 different methods - mean substitution, expectation maximisation and multiple imputation. So compare original x mean sub, compare original x em, compare original x mult imp. The goal is to determine which method imputes values that most closely resemble the complete data set. We have to use minimal maths so I am wondering if it is ok to just compare the means, do a paired sample t-test with 3 pairs, an independent t-test x 3 or run a bivariate correlations analysis.  Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure how we, on CV, would know what "minimal maths" is or what your teacher/professor would consider acceptable math for your assignment.  It sounds like this is a question better asked of your instructor.

Comment: And assuming your suggstion would be at the appropriate level for your instructor, you haven't explained how you'd calculate a mean for misclassification/incorrectly computed nominal values.  If the imputaiton algorithm generated a "Black" response when it the actual value was "Blue," how would you compute a mean and evaluate that?  You'll need to generally think about a simple method for handling and evaluating the accuracy for each type of variable you have.

Comment: Sorry - I assumed this was ok to ask since this is a forum for asking questions. I have asked my instructor who has not been helpful hence why I asked here. "You'll need to generally think about a simple method for handling and evaluating the accuracy for each type of variable you have." - this is what I was asking suggestions for?!

Comment: We can certainly guide you and provide recommendations, but just keep in mind we don't have any information about your course of what your professor is expecting. The phrase "minimal math" is somewhat subjective and means different things to different people. So what one person might consider "minimal math" Another might consider "complex," and your professor might have another idea all together. Here is what I suggest since you already reached out to your instructor without much luck. Can you update your question to describe a couple of ideas you've developed and then we can ... (con't)

Comment: (continued) certainly offer some guidance. You initially asked about one possible approach. In my previous comments I highlighted a criticism of that approach and why that likely won't work well. So, what I'd expect now is for you to possibly update your question with a revised approach. How would you revise your idea so that your evaluation of the Imputation algorithms will take into account your nominal data? The initial approach you described seems to ignore (or you haven't told us) how you would deal with nominal variables. Since this is homework, we won't just give you ... (continued)

Comment: (continued) answers, but we'll help you think through YOUR ideas and help you to come up with a good solution.  So yes, please ask away, but provide us with enough detail so we can see what you've done or considered (so we can gain insight into your reasoning) and why you think the approaches you've developed will be reasonable methods for evaluating the Imputation methods you described.

Comment: Also, my second comment/piece of advice would be to "pull up" a bit and think more simply about your problem. Don't get bogged down in trying to develop some fancy  statistical approach (just yet, anyway). Are there basic, simple measures you can use to evaluate performance? If so, what?